# Fluid simulation not generating fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a scene set up where the fluid generates from a "fluid" type. (not inflow or outflow, etc.) The fluid does not generate, it just makes a thin sheet at the top and corners of the spawner. It is pretty hard to describe the issue, so please refer to the screenshots and .blend file. I have already checked that everything is inside the domain, and nothing is intersecting with anything else. Thanks in advance!

[image: Here you can see the domain boundaries, the green cube is the fluid spawner.]
[image: Here is after the fluid has "generated". I have the fluid selected.]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For its Domain, tweak the value for "Final Resolution", I have tried other values and it works fine (For some reason 300 didn't work on my computer too). Choose another values and bake the fluid simulation again.